# Comparing values in a card game

Tags: ruby

I want to make a card game program that compares the values of cards assigned to `player_value` and `dealer_value`. If `player_value` is greater than `dealer_value`, it should display `"you win"`. Here is my code:

```
def get_card (card)
  type = case ((card-1)/13)
  when 0 then "of clubs"
  when 1 then "of diamonds"
  when 2 then "of hearts"
  when 3 then "of spades"
  end
  card = case (card%13)
  when 0 then "king #{type}"
  when 1 then "ace #{type}"                 
  when 11 then "jack #{type}"
  when 12 then "queen #{type}"
  else card%13
  end
  "#{card} #{type}"
end

def deal_cards
  total_cards = (1..52).to_a.shuffle
  player_value = [total_cards.pop, total_cards.pop]
  dealer_value = [total_cards.pop, total_cards.pop]
  puts "Your cards are #{get_card(player_value[0]).to_s} and #{get_card(player_value[1]).to_s}"
  puts "The dealer shows #{get_card(dealer_value[0])}"

  if(dealer_value > player_value)
    puts "You lose"
  else (player_value > dealer_value)
    puts "You win"
  end
  end  

deal_cards()
```

It is not clear to me why this is not working, and I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: By what criteria do you compare the cards? Does the hand with the highest combined face value win?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand why you assign an array to `player_value` and `dealer_value`, but you can't compare an array using `>` or `<`.

You have to retrieve the element from the array that you want to compare, and then use it in the `if`-`else` clause.

Also an `else` clause does not take another condition. An `else` will be used if all previous conditions fail. In your case, you should use `elsif`.

e.g.:

```
if(dealer_value[0] > player_value[0])
  puts "You lose"
elsif (player_value[0] > dealer_value[0])
  puts "You win"
end
```

Comment: the array class by itself does not work with the greater than or less than operator

Comment: Okay. I was wrong. Sorry about that. I confused it with `<=>`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer this object oriented solution to the same problem, since this is where Ruby really shines, and seeing it used in a procedural way really irks me. Object orientation adds a few more lines for scaffolding, but adds so much more in terms of legibility, reusability, and conceptual clarity.

---

We can represent the domain using three basic building blocks.

First, we need a `Card` object, able to hold some data (a rank and a suit) about itself, as well as the ability to represent itself as a string:

```
class Card
  SUITS = [:clubs, :diamonds, :spades, :hearts]
  RANKS = [:ace, *2..10, :jack, :queen, :king]

  attr_reader :suit, :rank

  def initialize(n)
    @suit = (n - 1) / 13
    @rank = (n - 1) % 13
  end

  def to_s
    "#{ RANKS[@rank] } of #{ SUITS[@suit] }"
  end
end
```

---

Next, we need a `Hand` object. Basically a collection of cards that can compare its strength to other hands, and also represent itself as a string:

```
class Hand

  attr_reader :cards

  def initialize(cards)
    @cards = cards
  end

  def <=>(other_hand)
    @cards.strength <=> other_hand.strength
  end

  def to_s
    @cards.map(&:to_s).join(", ")
  end

  private

  def strength
    @cards.map(&:rank).inject(:+)
  end
end
```

It is not clear from the question, how hand strength is determined. In this primitive implementation, it is simply the sum of the ranks of the cards in the hand.

---

Lastly, we need a `Deck` object. Something from which we can draw cards. We'll go with a standard 52-card deck:

```
class Deck
  def initialize
    @cards = (1..52).map { |n| Card.new(n) }.shuffle
  end

  def draw(number_of_cards = 1)
    [*@cards.pop(number_of_cards)]
  end
end
```

---

Now that we have our basic building blocks set up, using them is trivial:

```
def deal_cards
  deck = Deck.new

  player_hand = Hand.new(deck.draw(2))
  dealer_hand = Hand.new(deck.draw(2))

  puts "Your have: #{ player_hand }"
  puts "The dealer has: #{ dealer_hand }"

  if(player_hand > dealer_hand)
    puts "You win!"
  elsif(dealer_hand < player_hand)
    puts "Aw. You lose."
  else
    puts "Woah! It's a tie!"
  end
end
```

Notably this solution lacks error handling, for cases like passing an unknown `n` to the `Card` constructor, or `draw`ing from an empty deck, but can easily be added in.